# Calculate scrollable height

Tags: html, css

I have a section in my app where there are messages and after a certain height, it overflows and scrolls inside. This works fine but when the container below it expands past the minimum height it's set to overflow, the body overflows as well. The container below is an auto expanding input.

How do I adjust the height of my scrollable container when my input expands past its set minimum height? My input container maxes out at a height of 400px and has a starting height of 100px. My scrollable container has a starting height of 100% of the viewport height minus the starting height of the input container (100px).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="scrollable-container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum ullam deserunt velit unde odio officiis modi, assumenda at adipisci temporibus veritatis ex vel voluptas possimus animi perspiciatis officia ipsam molestiae!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis ducimus, tempore cupiditate ipsa magni aspernatur molestias debitis quo. Iusto, error exercitationem. Distinctio est beatae, saepe nisi iure ducimus exercitationem rem?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Molestias quos ullam laboriosam libero qui illum amet, numquam necessitatibus dolorem aliquid, inventore cumque repellendus accusamus ipsum deserunt beatae rem, quo neque!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Quidem consequatur aperiam fugit culpa deleniti sit dolore fugiat necessitatibus suscipit, beatae sint. Reprehenderit placeat iste molestias velit sunt accusamus doloribus repudiandae!
  </div>
  <div class="expanding-input">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable-container {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.expanding-input {
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
```

The code above works as long as the expanding input remains at a height of 90px. If it's set to anything above that, the body starts to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish something this using css flex.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:175px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.scrollable-container {

  border: 1px solid red;
  flex:5 1 0;
   overflow-y:auto;
}

.expanding-input {
  flex:1 1 0;
  border:1px solid green;  
  
}

.expanding-input textarea {
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>


<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="expanding-input">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum ullam deserunt velit unde odio officiis modi, assumenda at adipisci temporibus veritatis ex vel voluptas possimus animi perspiciatis officia ipsam molestiae!
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis ducimus, tempore cupiditate ipsa magni aspernatur molestias debitis quo. Iusto, error exercitationem. Distinctio est beatae, saepe nisi iure ducimus exercitationem rem?

  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```